# My App Should Not Be Installable On Android Watches

Tags: android

I recently found out (or better: one of my testers found out) that my app is installable on smartwatches running Android. It doesn't look very good though, and the app makes no sense on a smartwatch. So, might anyone be able to tell me what I can do against that? I already used search engines to find a solution, but I couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, when you upload your app to Google Play (through Developer Console), you can specify the devices that can install your APK. There you could disable any watches.

However if you are looking a way to specify this requirement in your code, you could have a look at the  element in the manifest [(Link)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

You can add something like this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature name="android.hardware.telephony" required="true"/>
<!-- android.hardware.telephony is for Telephony -->
```

The important part is to have `required="true"` attribute, and specify some feature, that is only available on phones, but not on watches.

I also recomment checking out the following tags that might help:

`<uses-configuration />`[(Link)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-configuration-element.html)

`<supports-screens />`[(Link)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Comment: Great answer, but you should probably make a short summary of the links, in case they once could go down. (Even though that's a rare case)

Comment: Well, if http://developer.android.com/ ever goes down, then there wouldn't be any reason to develop to Android anymore, or is there?

Comment: Perhaps they sometime change the subdomain, or change the links. Who knows? :P